# Make a check on AOP pointcut expression

Tags: spring, aop, expression, pointcut

I need to make a check in my pointcut expression like.
I have this bean:

```
<bean id="logConfig"
    class="com.celfocus.ufe.base.logging.domains.LoggingConfiguration">
    <property name="logDetails" value="STANDARD" />
    <property name="logLvl" value="COMPLETE" />
</bean>
```

In my aop pointcut expression i need to make a check to verify the value of bean property "logLvl".

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="ufeLogger">
        <aop:pointcut id="complete" expression="execution(* *.*(..)) and bean(logConfig)==COMPLETE" />
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="complete" method="logBefore" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

My expression isn't working... what I can change to make this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think that `and bean(logConfig)==COMPLETE` is a valid pointcut? Spring AOP uses AspectJ pointcut syntax, no Spring additions. Also you are not even referencing `logLvl` property, so has is this suppose to work?

Unfortunately to achieve this you must implement check manually. This isn't so intrusive though: simply inject `logConfig` into `ufeLogger` aspect and add a simple condition in `logBefore()` method.

Comment: i already had try it but when i put conditions inside the logBefore() method i can't intercept what i mean..

Answer (score 0):

This is the most relevant question, for solution below. I write aspect expressions from time to time. And expression might not work. You need to write right expression, which will be matched with your target method. I found a simple decision to check that everything is clear:

```
@Around(value="execution(* *.find(..))")
public Entity filterEntity(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
   Entity entity = (Entity) pjp.proceed(); // put breakpoint here
}
```

In Debug mode you can check target method real signature that is used for match with expression, in path `pjp.methodInvocation.method`

I hope this answer will save your time to find an error.

P.S If there are exists better decision to check expressions, glad to see it